What is the minimal setup needed to start to develop for InfiniBand networking on Windows and C++?
I want to create a project that uses InfiniBand for RDMA between the machines, however currently I have to develop my code in windows, as I have to be able to call code created by other teams who only develop for windows (so far). I am trying to find how feasible it would be to get started with infiniband for windows, but most of what I have found online is that windows is pretty much giving up on InfiniBand for windows. From what I can tell online, for Connect-X 4+ cards, I need to develop using the Network Direct SPI from Windows. However, this seems like its not being maintained:

And I cant find any instructions online how to use it anyway. Most (if not all) the examples I can find online about using infiniband in c++ use the library ibverbs, which is linux only.
What is the minimal setup needed (i.e. libraries, drivers, SDKs) to create a minimal C++ example of sharing data between to computers on Windows in 2024?

Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62301726/3740047 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/24815982/3740047

@Sedenion Yeah I saw those but they dont have an example of how to use Network Direct, I would like a hello world example of network direct but I couldnt work out how to really use it from the minimal documentation available. I also saw the easyRDMA project on github which works on windows/linux but there isnt an example of how to use that either.

Regarding easyRDMA: Have you tried looking through its source code, especially the tests (https://github.com/ni/easyrdma/blob/main/tests/tests.cpp)? There should hopefully be some from where you can see how to use the library.

There is also this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16411328/3740047. But yeah, looks like the learning curve is pretty steep.

@Sedenion Thanks, those tests look very useful!
